Patching windows compatibility settings to an .exe directly or through binary DLL, without the .SDB database?
In the windows compatibility administrator I have the following behaviors added from a database:

Is it possible to apply these windows compatibility patches directly to a .exe, or even by loading a .DLL that will add this behavior?
I did see that there is a registry entry made when the SDB is installed on windows, but it looks like it still needs the database to exist in some way.

